# Android talk back announcing incorrect content description for TextInputLayout when the the input type of EditText is password

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, talkback, accessibility

I have a TextInputLayout with the following structure in my android app.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:id="@+id/mEdit"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here the `maxLength` of `EditText` is *4*. However, after enabling talk back if we try to edit something into the password field the talkback announces content description like ***Bullet, Maximum length reached*** even if we didn't reach the `maxLength` of the `EditText`.

[image: Incorrect content description is shown when we enter 3rd password charector]

Thanks in advance for your valuable thoughts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` instead of using `EditText` in `TextInputLayout`.